# How to do vertical swipe

Tags: java, android, appium

I am able to scroll horizontally using following code

```
size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
System.out.println("size is "+size);

int startx = (int)(size.width*0.80);
int endx = (int)(size.width*0.20);
Thread.sleep(15000);
WebElement we = driver.findElementById("com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview:id/example_row_tv_title"));
TouchAction touch = new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver);
touch.longPress(we).moveTo(startx, endx).release().perform();
```

However I am not able to do vertical swipe(with below code) after getting the height of the screen and performing touch action.

```
int startx = (int)(size.width*0.80);
int endx = (int)(size.width*0.20);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

.moveTo() requires x and y parameters, not x1 and x2.  It's a fluke that your horizontal swipe works.  You are touching an element, then telling it to move to a specific location at x, y, not from x1 to x2.